# Error inflating Mvx.MvxLinearLayout after updating to MvvmCross 4.2.2 from 3.5.1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I just updated my project from MvvmCross 3.5.1 stable to 4.2.2. After fixing some other runtime exceptions that popped up after the update, I'm stuck with this one.

I am inflating a layout in an `MvxFragment`:

```
_rootView = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.my_layout, null);
```

This throws a `Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException` for `Mvx.MvxLinearLayout`. With the messages:

- Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
- Didn't find class \"Mvx.MvxLinearLayout\" on path: DexPathList[[zip file \"/data/app/com.myapp…

I have already installed the MvvmCross.Binding nuget package.

I the following base activity (which worked fine on 3.5.1):

### MvxActionBarActivity

```
/// <summary>
/// Mvx support for the native ActionBarActivity
/// </summary>
public abstract class MvxActionBarActivity
    : MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity
        , IMvxAndroidView
{
    protected MvxActionBarActivity()
    {
        BindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(this, this);
        this.AddEventListeners();
    }

    public object DataContext
    {
        get { return BindingContext.DataContext; }
        set { BindingContext.DataContext = value; }
    }

    public IMvxViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return DataContext as IMvxViewModel; }
        set
        {
            DataContext = value;
            OnViewModelSet();
        }
    }

    public void MvxInternalStartActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
    {
        base.StartActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext { get; set; }

    public override void SetContentView(int layoutResId)
    {
        var view = this.BindingInflate(layoutResId, null);
        SetContentView(view);
    }

    protected virtual void OnViewModelSet()
    {
    }
```

### MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity

```
public class MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity : AppCompatActivity
    , IMvxEventSourceActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        CreateWillBeCalled.Raise(this, bundle);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        CreateCalled.Raise(this, bundle);
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        DestroyCalled.Raise(this);
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        NewIntentCalled.Raise(this, intent);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        ResumeCalled.Raise(this);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        PauseCalled.Raise(this);
        base.OnPause();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        StartCalled.Raise(this);
    }

    protected override void OnRestart()
    {
        base.OnRestart();
        RestartCalled.Raise(this);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        StopCalled.Raise(this);
        base.OnStop();
    }

    public override void StartActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
    {
        StartActivityForResultCalled.Raise(this, new MvxStartActivityForResultParameters(intent, requestCode));
        base.StartActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        ActivityResultCalled.Raise(this, new MvxActivityResultParameters(requestCode, resultCode, data));
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        SaveInstanceStateCalled.Raise(this, outState);
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            DisposeCalled.Raise(this);
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public event EventHandler DisposeCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Bundle>> CreateWillBeCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Bundle>> CreateCalled;
    public event EventHandler DestroyCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Intent>> NewIntentCalled;
    public event EventHandler ResumeCalled;
    public event EventHandler PauseCalled;
    public event EventHandler StartCalled;
    public event EventHandler RestartCalled;
    public event EventHandler StopCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Bundle>> SaveInstanceStateCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<MvxStartActivityForResultParameters>> StartActivityForResultCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<MvxActivityResultParameters>> ActivityResultCalled;
}
```

Comment: Which class is your Activity overriding??

Comment: Like sJy said the activity might be an issue. 
And i just hope you got the MvvmCross.Binding.Droid Package referenced aswell in your project? Just since you me mentioned the MvvmCross.Binding package. 
Can you use MvxLinearLayout in code or does it show unknown there aswell?

Comment: @sJy I updated my question. Yes, I'm using MvvmCross.Binding.Droid, I can create an MvxLinearLayout in code.

Answer (score 0):

Switching my base activity to `MvxAppCompatActivity` fixed the issue.

Comment: Yeah, MvxAppCompatActivity wasn't available for 3.5.1 :)